# Why is Sikuli clicking on the wrong thing?

Tags: jython, sikuli

I am trying to use Sikuli to automate downloading photos from [reddit.com/r/EarthPorn](http://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn). For some reason, instead of clicking on the file image I have included, it clicks on `Homegroup` or `My Computer`.

Here's my code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are 2 possible reasons why your clicks land not where you are expecting them:

1. There are multiple regions that match your pattern (with the defined similarity).
2. Your offsets are imprecise.

To be sure the script does what you think it does, use `highlight` every time you define or match a region. `highlight` will display a red frame around the region and will be very helpful in understanding what region you are working with precisely. You can use it in the following manner:

```
matchingRegion = find("pattern.png")
matchingRegion.highlight(seconds)
```

Comment: I have done the highlight and the correct region is highlighted. I think it must be a bug with Sikuli. If the folder is empty, the first photo will successfully be placed, and then the rest mess up.

Comment: @Johnny That's highly unlikely. Clicking on objects is Sikuli core functionality I doubt it has any bug related to it. Try to check your timeouts as well. Specifically, add some wait time BEFORE the actual click.